# Django forms how to dynamically render fields in a loop

Tags: django, django-forms

Let's say I have a form with some fields.  Some of those fields are units of measurements:

```
['quantity_units', 'weight_units', 'dimension_units']
```

I also have these fields:

```
['quantity', 'weight', 'dimension']
```

I would like to display the unit of measurement right beside the field:

```
Quantity: ___________________  _______<unit of measurement drop-down list>______
```

I thought I should first loop through the form's fields.  For each iteration through the form's fields, I would check if the field name is in the units_list, if it is, then I would render the field and its unit field like so:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% for field_name in units_fields %}

        {% if field.name in field_name %}
            {{ field|add_class:"site-form-control" }} {{ form.field_name}}
        {% else %}
            {% ifchanged %}                     
                {{ field|add_class:"site-form-control" }}
            {% endifchanged %}
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This does not render the unit of measurement field with the drop-down list widget.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit:
I noticed that for some reason, Django displayed the `{{ field }}` twice and did not display `{{ form.field_name }}`.  To manually choose the field, I wrote a template filter to get the value given the key for a dictionary.  Then, I used it on the {{ form.fields }} which is an orderedDict

```
                            {% for field_name in units_fields %}

                                {% if field.name in field_name %}


                                    {{ form.fields|dict_key:field_name }}

                                {% else %}

                                    {% ifchanged %}

                                        {{ field|add_class:"site-form-control" }}
                                    {% endifchanged %}
                                {% endif %}

                            {% endfor %}
```

This renders the text representation of the field I want:

```
<django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x000001E5F35F3C18>
```

Any help to convert this text to an actual field is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to write a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) that returns a boundfield object `<django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at 0x0000025` instead of `<django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x000001E5F35F3C18>`

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_form_field(context, form, field_name):
    ''' Given a form and a field_name, it returns form.field'''
    try:
        field = form[field_name]
    except KeyError:
        field = None

    return field
```